Random spawning node
I want a rectangular node called “Start” to appear between the coordinates 1000x1000 and 950x950 once per simulation. For this I have the function "setRandomPosition"
setRandomPosition(); {     double x = uniform(950, 1000);     double y = uniform(950, 1000);     Start.setPos(x, y, 0);
}
which is initialized in the Main, On StartUp,setRandomPosition();.
This is the only function at all.
Everything is compiled, but on execution, I get a StackOverflow with error: at_1_try.Main.setRandomPosition(Main.java:634). Error, while execution here
The ultimate goal is to create a random area as “spawn-point” with pedSource.
I can't get any further... Does anyone have a solution available for this specific problem or a better method?

You are not calling this function once ("on startup of Main") but many times. Pls share how and where else it is called. Or ensure it only throws the traceln once, so you can see the rest of the error msg (at the beginning of the console). This is where the juicy bits are :)

Sorry for being a noob. I have no idea where and how to place tracln. And yes, I read the support section about traceln... Still lost

no worries, we all started as noobs :) share a screenshot of where you make the call. And make 100% sure this is the only place where you call it
